# Postegresql SQL DISTINCT with INNER JOIN keep getting duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im using inner join in two tables like this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cedula,
       c.idclave_nombre,
       o.fechaproxima_llamada,
       c.ubicacion,
       c.notas,
       c.nombres,
       c.apellidos,
       c.sector,
       c.empresa,
       c.acreedor,
       c.analista,
       c.sucursal,
       o.motivo,
       c.ps,
       c.fecha_nacimiento,
       c.sexo,
       DATE_PART(
               'YEAR',
               AGE(CURRENT_DATE, c.fecha_nacimiento)
       ) as edad
FROM tbl_clientes c
         INNER JOIN tbl_observaciones o ON c.idclave_nombre = o.idclave_nombre
```

but im getting duplicates, the key should be column 'c.cedula':

```
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+--------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+--------+--------+------------------+----+----------------+----+----+
|cedula    |idclave_nombre      |fechaproxima_llamada|ubicacion|notas|nombres |apellidos|sector   |empresa       |acreedor  |analista|sucursal|motivo            |ps  |fecha_nacimiento|sexo|edad|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+--------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+--------+--------+------------------+----+----------------+----+----+
|8-796-2306|AANANKHA 25-05-22-AZ|2024-01-15          |PAGO     |null |AANANKHA|QUARLESS |E PRIVADA|BAC CREDOMATIC|PANACREDIT|ROGELIO |null    |OFRECER EXTRAMONEY|null|1986-04-27      |F   |37  |
|8-796-2306|AANANKHA 25-05-22-AZ|null                |PAGO     |null |AANANKHA|QUARLESS |E PRIVADA|BAC CREDOMATIC|PANACREDIT|ROGELIO |null    |?                 |null|1986-04-27      |F   |37  |
|8-796-2306|AANANKHA 25-05-22-AZ|null                |PAGO     |null |AANANKHA|QUARLESS |E PRIVADA|BAC CREDOMATIC|PANACREDIT|ROGELIO |null    |INTRO             |null|1986-04-27      |F   |37  |
|8-796-2306|AANANKHA 25-05-22-AZ|null                |PAGO     |null |AANANKHA|QUARLESS |E PRIVADA|BAC CREDOMATIC|PANACREDIT|ROGELIO |null    |OJO               |null|1986-04-27      |F   |37  |
|8-796-2306|AANANKHA 25-05-22-AZ|null                |PAGO     |null |AANANKHA|QUARLESS |E PRIVADA|BAC CREDOMATIC|PANACREDIT|ROGELIO |null    |PAGO              |null|1986-04-27      |F   |37  |
|8-796-2306|AANANKHA 25-05-22-AZ|null                |PAGO     |null |AANANKHA|QUARLESS |E PRIVADA|BAC CREDOMATIC|PANACREDIT|ROGELIO |null    |PRELI             |null|1986-04-27      |F   |37  |
|8-796-2306|AANANKHA 25-05-22-AZ|null                |PAGO     |null |AANANKHA|QUARLESS |E PRIVADA|BAC CREDOMATIC|PANACREDIT|ROGELIO |null    |null              |null|1986-04-27      |F   |37  |
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+--------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+--------+--------+------------------+----+----------------+----+----+
```

i use that inner join because i need to show two columns in a table.

Lets say i just want from those 7 records, to show the first one, the one that have **o.fechaproxima_llamada** not null, but there will be times for example this another client that have **o.fechaproxima_llamada** null, but it only need to be shown one of those two records.

```
+---------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+-----+------------+-------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+---------+----------+----+----------------+----+----+
|cedula   |idclave_nombre   |fechaproxima_llamada|ubicacion|notas|nombres     |apellidos    |sector   |empresa|acreedor  |analista|sucursal |motivo    |ps  |fecha_nacimiento|sexo|edad|
+---------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+-----+------------+-------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+---------+----------+----+----------------+----+----+
|8-984-255| NOEMI 13-09-18-V|null                |D        |null |NOEMI YOANIS|RAMOS SALDAÑA|E PRIVADA|null   |FINANCOMER|RAIZA   |LOS ANDES|ATENDIDO  |null|1999-07-12      |F   |24  |
|8-984-255| NOEMI 13-09-18-V|null                |D        |null |NOEMI YOANIS|RAMOS SALDAÑA|E PRIVADA|null   |FINANCOMER|RAIZA   |LOS ANDES|PRELIMINAR|null|1999-07-12      |F   |24  |
+---------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+-----+------------+-------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+---------+----------+----+----------------+----+----+
```

what you recommend me in this case?

thank you

When i use the query without DISCTINCT im getting this results see first table CEDULA = 8-712-1266.

```
+----------+------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+-------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+----+----------------+----+----+
|cedula    |idclave_nombre    |fechaproxima_llamada|ubicacion|notas|nombres      |apellidos    |sector   |empresa                                      |acreedor   |analista|sucursal|motivo  |ps  |fecha_nacimiento|sexo|edad|
+----------+------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+-------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+----+----------------+----+----+
|8-712-1266| ALEXIS 28-10-16-K|null                |EE       |null |ALEXIS MIGUEL|MARCHADO     |E PRIVADA|TRANSPORTE Y MULTISERVICIOS,S.A.  ( DON LEE )|null       |null    |null    |ATENDIDO|null|1971-11-12      |M   |51  |
|8-766-118 | FRANCISCO 31-8-11|null                |CERRADO  |null |FRANCISCO    |ROMERO CEDEÑO|E PRIVADA|CONALVIA                                     |INSTACREDIT|JHANMARY|AVE PERU|ATENDIDO|S   |1983-01-05      |M   |40  |
|8-766-118 | FRANCISCO 31-8-11|null                |CERRADO  |null |FRANCISCO    |ROMERO CEDEÑO|E PRIVADA|CONALVIA                                     |INSTACREDIT|JHANMARY|AVE PERU|ATENDIDO|S   |1983-01-05      |M   |40  |
+----------+------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+-------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+----+----------------+----+----+
```

but when i use

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (c.cedula)
       c.cedula,
       c.idclave_nombre,
       o.fechaproxima_llamada,
       c.ubicacion,
       c.notas,
       c.nombres,
       c.apellidos,
       c.sector,
       c.empresa,
       c.acreedor,
       c.analista,
       c.sucursal,
       o.motivo,
       c.ps,
       c.fecha_nacimiento,
       c.sexo,
       DATE_PART(
               'YEAR',
               AGE(CURRENT_DATE, c.fecha_nacimiento)
       ) as edad
FROM tbl_clientes c
         INNER JOIN tbl_observaciones o ON c.idclave_nombre = o.idclave_nombre
```

column cedula is changed like this, its like it removes - and add 0 as first char:

```
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+-----------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------+----------+--------+---------+------+----+----------------+----+----+
|cedula   |idclave_nombre      |fechaproxima_llamada|ubicacion|notas|nombres          |apellidos          |sector   |empresa             |acreedor  |analista|sucursal |motivo|ps  |fecha_nacimiento|sexo|edad|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+-----------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------+----------+--------+---------+------+----+----------------+----+----+
|-        |ALFONSO 8-08-07     |null                |I        |X23- |ALFONSO          |CHAN               |JUBILADO |null                |null      |null    |null     |null  |null|1944-04-07      |M   |79  |
|008491059|ALEXANDER 17-02-20-V|null                |D        |null |ALEXANDER ENRIQUE|VILLALOBOS VALENCIA|E PRIVADA|SERVICIOS SIGMA, S.A|LA EXITOSA|null    |CALIDONIA|INTRO |null|1972-03-07      |M   |51  |
|02225038 |LUIS 21-06-22-L     |null                |D        |null |LUIS ALONSO      |ROSALES ALVARADO   |E PRIVADA|PPG                 |null      |null    |null     |INTRO |null|1980-03-09      |M   |43  |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+-----------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------+----------+--------+---------+------+----+----------------+----+----+
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Consider using `DISTINCT ON(...)` construct.  Look for explanation here: https://www.geekytidbits.com/postgres-distinct-on/

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for the tip, its better now my post? sorry about that

Comment: Yes. That's much better. Thanks!

Comment: did you apply a where on the second query to make sure you are comparing the same rows as the first one?

Comment: yes, but it changes the data it removes - and place a 0 at first char, its strange

Comment: I mean, it is missing "where c.cedula = '8-796-2306'" at the end of your second query

Comment: yeah thats was just test, that where is depending if user select that query to search by cedula. its not required.

Comment: the distinct works good only it changes my data from 8-796-2306 to 087962306 when im not using WHERE statement. If i put another column for disctinc as NAME or NOMBRE, then Cedula is in correct format

Comment: that's not what your edited question shows. It neither has the where nor shows what you just commented.

Comment: Anyways... your question has already been answered. If you have a new situation please make a new question since this is not a chat, and you are altering your initial post.

Comment: done edited, the issue is without the WHERE. At the end it changes the string thats my issue

Comment: good ! thank you @AprendendoNext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use DISTINCT it will consider a combination of all retrieved columns.

You can use DISTINCT ON to force some keys, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (c.cedula)
       c.cedula,
       c.idclave_nombre,
       o.fechaproxima_llamada,
       c.ubicacion,
       c.notas,
       c.nombres,
       c.apellidos,
       c.sector,
       c.empresa,
       c.acreedor,
       c.analista,
       c.sucursal,
       o.motivo,
       c.ps,
       c.fecha_nacimiento,
       c.sexo,
       DATE_PART(
               'YEAR',
               AGE(CURRENT_DATE, c.fecha_nacimiento)
       ) as edad
FROM tbl_clientes c
         INNER JOIN tbl_observaciones o ON c.idclave_nombre = o.idclave_nombre
where c.cedula = '8-796-2306'
```

It will consider the first ocurrence in case of duplicates, which you can solve by using ORDER conditions to define who gets selected first.

Comment: cedula have to be twice in the select query then?

Comment: The field(s) on parenthesis represent the "primary key" for the DISTINCT ON clause.
For c.cedula to appear, it has to be declared again as a field to be displayed.

Comment: It means that only the first occurrence of a unique value for c.cedula will appear in your results, the others with the same value will be ignored.

Comment: it works, but for some reason the distinct changes the data to another format from 8-796-2306 to 0879606

Comment: sorry i tried to edit your post not mine, i added to mine original post more info